# how to implement a new kind of compare&swap instruction

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, compare-and-swap

I need to implement (pseudo-code) a new type of compare&swap(a,b)  (CAS) object
(let's call the new type CAS2) .

CAS and CAS2 objects both support the read operation which returns the
object value.

They both support the compare&swap(a,b) operation, but while on CAS
this operation return true/false and changes the object value to b if
it is equal to a, on CAS2 this operation has the same effect, but
instead of  returning  true/false, it should always return the object
value prior to the operation.

For example:

If   the CAS object value is 4,
compare&swap (4,5) will return true and change the value to 5, but on
CAS2 object ,compare&swap (4,5) will return 4 and also change the
value to 5 .
If  the CAS object value is 4, so compare&swap (5,6) will return false
and will do nothing , but on CAS2  compare&swap (5,6) will return 4
and also do nothing.
The CAS2 object should be implemented using only one CAS object and
the implementation should be wait-free and linearizable.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The variant you are requesting is actually the mainsteam one. Implementing such an instruction without mutex requires hardware support, like a dedicated instruction. See the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) on that topic for further details.